# Shopify import csv products

Tags: import, shopify

I would like to know if there is a default feature for importing products export files in  json/xml/csv format and if this can be called daily with a cron or something automatically.

Thanks,

Tibi

Answer (score 1):

You are free to create a private App that has scope permissions to write_products, write_inventory and read_locations. With that, you can establish a script that can parse your json/xml/csv and update inventory. That script can be scheduled to run as often as you need. Shopify is an ideal platform for the use of scripting to accomplish many manual tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David. You need to create a custom App in your store and submit your data to a script(you can use PHP) triggered by CRON hosted on a server which will create a record using Product API.

**Step 1**: Go to Apps tab in admin section of your store. Scroll down and click on Manage private apps, create an App here to generate API keys and password.

**Step 2**: Create and host(on a secured server) a script that will use API keys generated in previous step to create new product record using https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product#create

**Step 3**: Fetch your data in any format and send this data in JSON format to your Shopify store using API. A new product record will be created in your store.

Note: You can test this API by using credential created in Step 1 on Postmen tool you can refer https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product#create. You will have to hit Example URL generated in Private app from Step 1.

Comment: Thank you both, the script that will be runned daily is used for synchronizing the stocks of the products. Would be there other option on updating the stocks?